# stop audio to all scenes using slider in main menu in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

stop audio to all scenes using slider in main menu in unity

I am using different sounds in differnt scenes but problem is that i can't stop all sounds using slider in menu it's only stop menu sound or sound for scene but when my game over menu button appear i clicked on that then sound new apear as i am using DontDestroyOnLoad in Background script

public class BGSoundScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

//Play Global
private static BGSoundScript instance = null;
public static BGSoundScript Instance
{
    get { return instance; }
}

void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null && instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
 public void SetVolume(float vol)
{
    musicVolume = vol;
}
//Play Gobal End
```

### }

//i am using BGSoundScript.Instance.audioSrc.Play(); and //BGSoundScript.Instance.audioSrc.Pause(); in other script but that also not //work for me

Answer (score 1):

Use Audio Mixer. Here is a little tutorial about Audio Mixer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOaQp2x-io0